# Email address sign up text entry box in rails error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

Firstly, this is a rookie question. I am a beginner. I am trying to just have a simple newsletter sign up. As well as having a pop up afterwards that says something along the lines of Thanks for signing up etc..

I am getting this error from my logs:

```
Started POST "/signups" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-11-01 02:29:27 -0200
ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (2.0ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".*           FROM
"schema_migrations"
Processing by SignupsController#create as HTML
Parameters: {"email"=>"akjbfkjsbdfkja@gmail.com"}
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 16ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

NameError (uninitialized constant SignupsController::Signups):
app/controllers/signups_controller.rb:3:in `create'
```

Here is my controller:

```
class SignupsController < ApplicationController
def create
    Signups.create! :email => params[:email]



end
end
```

And my model

```
class Signup < ActiveRecord::Base

validates :email, :presence => true
end
Signup.save
```

Here is my html Form

```
<form id="register-newsletter" method="POST" action= "/signups">
                        <input type="text" name="email" required="" placeholder="Enter your email address">
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-custom-3" value="SIGN UP">
                        </form>
```

thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Model name is `Signup` instead of `Signups`

```
class SignupsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    Signup.create(email: params[:email])
  end
end
```